What's an OLAP cube and how does it differ from star schema?
There are 2, I guess related concepts: star schema and olap cube, what are their differences? When should one be chosen over the other?

Did you try to read the Wiki article OLAP cube? It says that star schema is often used for OLAP cubes. There is more associated logic with the OLAP cube (slicing the dimensions and computing some functions fast). Related terms are "multi-dimensional array" and  "tensor".
